# Merge repositories into monorepo

Tags: git, lerna, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I trying to merge a couple of repo into a monorepo. So all the repositories will be inside a folder called packages/.

I want the git history of all the repo to be merged. As the migration process will take time, I also would like to merge the changes that are done on the individual repo to the monorepo.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: It seems possible, but this is not going to be easy. Have you estimated the time it is going to take? Maybe doing a partial import can help you with that estimation. I would strongly suggest to put the older repos in "read-only" mode during this migration, but it all depends on how much time it is going to take. Remember git is descentralized, so commits can stil be added to the local clones, and sent later to the server so devs should be able to handle this for this specific migration window.

Comment: As there is continuous development happening in older repos, it would be difficult to make it read only. So we wait until thing become a bit more quiet before making this migration.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the packages to exist and be developed on simultaneously in the monorepo and in their own repos? Or is it just that you want to migrate one package at a time into the monorepo, not all the packages at once? So that for each individual repo, it is moved completely in one moment, and all development for that repo transitions to using the monorepo?